# How can I view data from database using textview?

Tags: android, database

I'm doing an admin page that can view the users that exist in the system. My idea is to show a list of the users and the details in one page. I heard that using listview is very tedious. Is there any other way that is easy?

Maybe view in textview but I dont know how it works. I must put in a lot of textview on my xml?

A simple task that I need to know how to do. I just need to know how to view datas in a page, using any method.

Thank you very much! Hope to get responds soooon! =D

Dayne

---

Hello again

Here's how a listview looks like:

```
package log1.log2;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AdminMain extends ListActivity {


static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
"Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands","Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru"
  };


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
```

For the code above, the data is written in the codes itself. My data is in my database and I need it to be shown on the listview. I do not know how to do it. I tried a few ideas I had:

```
public class AdminMain extends ListActivity {

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    private String TEST;




    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          db.open();
          Cursor c = (Cursor) db.getAllUser();  
          final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {

            };


        TEST=c.getString(1).toString();

          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TEST));
          getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

I declare a string and I tried retrieving data from database and save it to the string which is TEST. And then I tried showing it on the listview :

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TEST));
              getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

But I cant put 'TEST' in the listview. The error, `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(AdminMain, int, String) is undefined.` will appear.

I hope somebody will give me a good answer for this. I'm looking forward to your replies. Thank you for taking your time reading this.

-Dayne

---

### Hello Sephy

Here's what I edited.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          db.open();
          Cursor c = (Cursor) db.getAllUser();  
          /*final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {

            };*/

          final String[] TEST = c.getString(1);

        //TEST[]=c.getString(1).toString();

          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
          getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
```

As you can see I tried to put data from my database straight into the array but it can't work; `final String[] TEST = c.getString(1);`. The error message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]` appeared.

Comment: Indeed, It's going bad because you try to put a String in something that's supposed to take an Array of String. Create a new ArrayList of String for instance and put it in your adapter instead of TEST. How many users do you have in your database?

Comment: There's no limit number of users you see.... people can just come and create a new account.. :/

Comment: I edited after reading your kind comment Sephy... read my question above. Edited. Still can't work hough.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` is tedious to use, but sometimes, if for instance your dataset is quite big and repetitive, you might want to consider using `ListView`.
If you still don't want to, you can create a `ScrollView` plus a header in a `TextView` in your xml for instance, and then in your java, you use a for loop or a while to loop on your database result, and every time you have one set of data ready, you create a new `TextView` and add it to the `ScroolView`. It would be something like that :

```
if (yourCursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
      //prepare your data       
      TextView tv = new TextView(yourContext);
      tv.setText("yourData");
      // you can set id, tag, text color, font, ...
      yourScrollView.addView(tv);
    } while (yourCursor.moveToNext());
}
yourCursor.close();
yourDB.close();
```

Comment: I have the code for listview but it;s hardcoded. Can you help me with that? I need to retrieve data from database and show it in the listview instead of hardcoding.